# How many windmill rotations does it take to send a rocket to Mars?

Tags: space, space-travel, energy

I want to live in a pollution free world, where all creatures can breath clean air.

I also want to live in a high-end space civilization, where its possible to travel to other planets in our solar system (e.g. Mars).

I therefore need a lot of clean energy, and I'm researching the best source.

This question is related to wind energy.

**Question:** How many rotations from an average-size land windmill does it take to produce the energy needed to travel to Mars?

The rocket used for Mars travel would be something like [SpaceX's "Big Fucking" Mars Rocket](http://www.spacex.com/mars)

**EDIT**

To simplify things a bit: The wind-mill produces the rocket fuel on site (no power lost in transmission and storage).
The fuel is liquid oxygen and hydrogen.

Comment: First, you need to define how efficient is your storage. Then, energy output depends on more than size and count of turns. And last, pollution-free rocket system is something we don't really have, so it's quite ard to calculate.

Comment: I have edited the question. Pollution from rockets are tolerated until a better alternative is found.

Comment: I suppose in such a world the technology for near loss-less energy storage has to exist. There are further assumptions to make, how is that energy used to propel the spaceship? Rockets are basically fuel tanks that are pointed in the right direction and then lit at one end, thus the comparison to the SpaceX rocket is mostly useless because it mostly lifts itself. The question is basically about the energy per kilo efficiency of your energy storage and propulsion system which determines how to reach escape velocity.

Comment: Once in orbit the energy to reach Mars is near zero, unless you set a time frame you can push your space ship to Mars given time ;)

Comment: Please see edit. The rocket im referring to is not electrical, its powered by normal rocket fuel. The rocket fuel is produced by power from a windmill.

Comment: Also: Once in orbit around the earth, it does take a lot of energy to break lose of earth gravity, and it take energy to slow down when Mars is reached.

Comment: There are lots of different kinds of "normal rocket fuel", like super-toxic hypergolic fuels and not-so-toxic-but-carbon-heavy kerosene derivatives like RP-1. But when you want to be eco-friendly, you are likely talking about liquid oxygen + liquid hydrogen which can be made by splitting water with electrolysis and then separating and compressing the resulting oxygen and hydrogen.

Comment: By the way: "no power lost on storage" might be too much of a simplification. The main problem of LOX and LH is that they need permanent cooling and even then can not be stored for long.

Comment: Yes, probably the same problem todays rocket-fuel producers have. 
I think it should be left out to simplify the question. What I want to know is whether or not windmills are the energy of the future, and this question tries to answer that. Does it take a windmill hundreds of years to produce the amount of energy needed, or what? Thats the essence of my question.

Comment: Once you are in space, you can largely trade thrust or velocity for time. If you are willing to let the trip take longer, you don't need to bring as much fuel. The problem with manned missions is that usually we want to minimize *both* travel time (to reduce the crew's and vehicle's exposure to harmful radiation, and reduce the amount of consumables brought along) *and* fuel and propellant mass (to increase the payload capacity of the spacecraft). Reducing one of those is relatively simple, in purely theoretical terms; reducing both at the same time is extremely difficult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## In 2 years, 8 months (or 9 hours if you go nuclear)

[To electrolyse water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis_of_water#Thermodynamics_2), you need at least $286 kJ/mol$

[Liquid oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_oxygen)  has a density of $1.14 g/ml$

[Oxygen has an atomic weight of 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen), i.e. $16 g/mol$

So for every liter of Oxygen — and its corresponding amount of Hydrogen — you need to use $19.1 MJ$, which is $5.3 kWh$.

[The Saturn V used about 1.6 million liters of liquid Oxygen for its first, second and third stages](http://www.space.com/18422-apollo-saturn-v-moon-rocket-nasa-infographic.html). Assuming we then use Hydrogen and Oxygen in all stages (the Saturn V did not but let us play at that) this lands us on about $8.5 GWh$.

[A 1.5 MW wind turbine at 25% capacity factor](https://www.wind-watch.org/faq-output.php) would produce that amount of energy in about 2 years and 8 months. This gets you as far as the Moon, not Mars, but now you know what ball park you are in.

Oh... and as a side note: a bog-standard 1000 MWe (*) nuclear reactor — which is [cleaner than wind power](https://corporate.vattenfall.com/globalassets/corporate/sustainability/reports/life_cycle_assessment.pdf) (pages 16 to 18), and also [safer](http://www.forbes.com/sites/jamesconca/2012/06/10/energys-deathprint-a-price-always-paid/) — generates that same amount of energy in 8.5 **hours**.

<sub>(*) MegaWatt electrical</sub>

Comment: It seems that Vattenfall solved the deconstruction and long term storage issues. A shame they don't actually implement this tech.

Comment: @Burki The application for long term storage — the KBS-3 solution — has been handed in to the Swedish authorities and is in the process of being approved. Finland has already approved it. The start of construction and acceptance of the first storage capsules for both countries is expected within a decade. http://www.skb.com/news/swedish-method-gains-approval-in-finland-2/

Comment: And how is this taken into account in your "nuclear power is cleaner" calculation? Could you provide some insights there?

Comment: The document I linked to — https://corporate.vattenfall.com/globalassets/corporate/sustainability/reports/life_cycle_assessment.pdf — addresses decommissioning as well. It is a **Life Cycle Assessment** and in that decommissioning is required to be included.